# How to include the search query of a search engine into my title?

Tags: search-engine, title, meta

i have often seen websites which are indexed in search engines with a content like: Search now for "search query" ("search query" is the word I have entered in the search engine (for example Google)). So somehow they take the search query and put it into their title. Is there a possibility to do this and if yes, does Google like it or not?

Answer (score 0):

Your page would need to use the [HTTP referrer header](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referrer) to determine what the query to the search engine was. It could then use that information to determine what words to highlight on the page, include in the title, etc.

Comment: but how can a search engine bot find this site with the title since the bot wont type a search query into his own search engine?